# Sniffing data on uClinux local loopback

Tags: sockets, localhost, ethernet, uclinux

I am looking for a way to monitor/sniff local loopback traffic inside a uClinux embedded device.  I have several processes that communicate via the local loopback and want to capture this traffic on an outside machine.  So I want to direct a copy of all local loopback traffic out the "real" Ethernet to a specific IP address, namely that of my Windows PC running a sniffer.

Is this possible, maybe with `iptables` or something?  The traffic is all UDP, between a few dozen ports.  If not, I was thinking about writing some code to open a raw socket, read in the packets in question and forward them to my fixed IP address.  Would it work to capture local loopback traffic with a raw socket?

Comment: This question should be made on `Unix & Linux`, `Server Fault`, `Super User` or similar StackExchange site, because Stack overflow is aimed to programming, and we discuss based on source code :).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about a code-based solution as well, so I posted here.  I expanded my question to indicate that.